# Is there a way to dynamically change color of multiple buttons at once in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am coding a maze game. The player has to uncover a path from the top left square to the bottom right square in a 6 x 6 grid (made of flatbuttons). When the player clicks on a button, it turns green if the move is on the path and red if it is not. However, I want the square the player most recently clicked on to be purple. For example, if I previously clicked on square (0,0) I want it to remain purple until another square is pressed. Then, I want that square to turn purple and (0,0) to return to its starting grey color. However, I can't find a way to change the color of a button that I am not currently pressing.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:mazeeapp/HomePageClass.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'GameButton&MazeClasses.dart';
import 'package:mazeeapp/main.dart';
import 'PathGenerator.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class GameButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  int onPath = 0;
  bool testOnPath() {
    if (this.onPath == 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  bool testIfLegal(lastMove) {
    return (((this.id - lastMove).abs() == 1) ^
    ((this.id - lastMove).abs() == 10));
  }

  bool moveCheck() {
    if (this.testIfLegal(lastMove) & this.testOnPath()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  GameButton(this.id, lastMove);
  @override
  _GameButtonState createState() => _GameButtonState();
}

class _GameButtonState extends State<GameButton> {
 
  // this code going to be what happens on button press event

  String buttonPress() {
    displayImage=true; 
    
//start timer only one time then return time elapsed once the maze has been completed.
    bool shouldClockStart=true;
    if(shouldClockStart) {
      clock.start();
      final shouldClockStart=false;
    }
    if(this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        timeElapsed = clock.elapsed;
      });
    }
    //if the person's previous move was correct this if statement will run and and utilize the moveCheck function
    if (!lastMoveIncorrect) {
      if (widget.moveCheck()) {
        image="assets/greencheck.jpg";
        lastMove = widget.id;
        color = Colors.green;
        //once square is correctly found it is taken off the path. ie the player cannot go backwards on the path
        widget.onPath=0;
        errors.add("correct");
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 450), () {
          if(this.mounted) {
            setState(() {
              color = Colors.purple;
              displayImage = false;
            });
          }
        });


//ending conditions: what app should do upon completion of maze. only triggers if player hits button 99 and it is a correct move
        if ((widget.id == 99) & this.mounted) {
          setState(() {
            appComplete=true;
          });

        }

// end of ending conditions. next else statement is what happens if player's current move is incorrect but their lastmove was correct
      } else {
        image="assets/redx.jpg";
        color = Colors.red;
        lastMoveIncorrect = true;
        //now that we know that player's most recent move was incorrect we need to determine whether move was not on path or invalid for documentation purposes in json file. this code does that

        if(widget.testIfLegal(lastMove)) {
          errors.add("incorrect");
        }
        else {
          errors.add("invalid");
        }

        //end of classifying player's incorrect move
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds:450), () {
          if(this.mounted) {
            setState(() {
              color = Colors.purple;
              displayImage = false;
            });
          }

        });

        setState(() => numberErrors++);
      }
    }
// end of current if statement. Now if the player's previous move was incorrect the following statements will run-requiring the player to input the last correct move.
    if (lastMoveIncorrect) {
      if (widget.id == lastMove) {
        color = Colors.green;
        errors.add("Correct");
        image="assets/greencheck.jpg";
        lastMoveIncorrect = false;
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 450), () {
          if(this.mounted) {
            setState(() {
              color = Colors.purple;
               displayImage = false;
            });
          }
        });


      } else {
        setState(() => numberErrors++);
        image="assets/redx.jpg";
        displayImage=true;
        color = Colors.red;
        if(widget.testIfLegal(lastMove)) {
          errors.add("incorrect");
        }
        else {
          errors.add("invalid");
        }
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 450), () {
          if(this.mounted) {
            setState(() {
              color = Colors.purple;
              displayImage = false;
            });
          }
        });

      }
    }
    // this line needed so flutter knows to dynamically rebuild entire grid of buttons on every press
      controller.add(widget.id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
      child: FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: displayImage?Image.asset(image):null,
        color: color,
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            color=Colors.grey; 
          });
          buttonPress();
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Maze extends StatefulWidget {
  int numberErrors = 0;
  List<GameButton> empty_grid = [
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) new GameButton(i, lastMove)
  ];

  @override
  _MazeState createState() => _MazeState();
}

class _MazeState extends State<Maze> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
}
```

The list of 100 gameButtons is then wrapped inside a gridView and returned.

Comment: You can create a function in GameButton to change color, why just pressing?

Comment: @hoangquyy I tried that but I can't figure out how to create a function that can change the color of only one button at a time. Note that all of my buttons are instances of the GameButton class. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Seem like you use color variable as a global variable but not an attribute of GameButton. That was the reason you can't change the color of only one button. Why don't you set an attribute name color in GameButton?

Comment: @hoangquyy good idea thanks